# Calling a private static variable in java from a different class

Tags: java, class, static

I think this might be a straightforward question but I have a class that has a private static int variable that is being incremented within the class and I want to display this value in a second class. However, it keeps printing out 0 even though it has been incremented.

Same code would be

```
public class Test{

      private static int toIncrement;

      public static int returnValue{
          return toIncrement;
      }

      public void test{
         for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
               toIncrement++;
         }
      }
 }
```

So the above code runs and then from another class I call Test.returnValue();
and this returns 0

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It's all there.

Comment: @hexafraction: Ah the code above doesn't even compile. To the original poster: Please don't waste our time by posting "junk" code for us to review. If you have a serious problem and want serious help, post only *real* code.

Comment: How does your class compiles in the first place.

Comment: DO you know how to write a method in Java?

Answer (score 0):

> So the above code runs and then from another class I call
>   Test.returnValue(); and this returns 0

When you say above code runs, does not mean that your `test` method will execute automatically, without being called from anywhere. If you call your `test` method first and then try to get the `Test.returnValue()` then the value should not be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh. where do I begin?

```
public void test{
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        toIncrement++;
  }
}
```

That's not a constructor. It would need the `void` removed. That's not even valid due to lack of parentheses.

```
public static int returnValue{
  return toIncrement;
}
```

Again, parentheses.

```
private static int toIncrement;

public static int returnValue{
    return toIncrement;
}
```

Is this really meant to be static? Either make it static, and call `Test.test()` or make it non-static and call the constructor correctly.

Comment: *"Even if it were, it would be useless as `toIncrement` is static and it would break."* It wouldn't break. Static variables can be used in a non-static context (only the reverse is untrue).

Comment: @arshajii Thanks, I always have trouble confusing the 2, though it seems intuitive now.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the argument brackets in your methods.
Should be:

```
public class Test{

    private static int toIncrement;

    public static int returnValue(){
    return toIncrement;
    }

    public void test(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        toIncrement++;
    }
}
```

But seeing that you do not call test() anywhere, I assume that you thought it was a constructor. To make it the constructor remove "void"
So its just:

```
public test()
{
    code here
}
```

When you do this, the code will run automatically as you run your program(As long as this is you main class, if not you need to make an instance of it for the constructor to run.)

Answer (score 0):

Use a static block!

```
public class Test{

      private static int toIncrement;

      public static int returnValue(){
          return toIncrement;
      }

      static {
         for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
               toIncrement++;
         }
      }
 }
```